# Passing a default parameters for "rails generate" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'd like to pass the parameters in "rails generate" commands by default.

For example, I'd like to always have "-=rspec" to generate rspec files associate with the model. Also I'd like to avoid generating fixture files.

In generating controllers, I don't want a helper generated.

I thought there'd be a way to specify the default paramers somewhere in the code, probably in "config" or "script" directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define what kind of generator you want in your application.rb like that :

```
 config.generators do |g|
   g.template_engine :haml
   g.test_framework  :rspec
 end
```